# I am trying to loop though api data for tide Hight in a set time frame and find all the data for each day of the month

Tags: javascript, loops

```
for (let i = 1; i < data.values.length; i++) {
        TimeStart = data.values[i].time;
        HightStart = data.values[i].value;
        TimeEnd = data.values[i].time;
        HightEnd = data.values[i].value;
        if (TimeStart.slice(11, 16) == start) {
          Date = TimeStart.slice(0, 10);
          TimeStart = TimeStart.slice(11, 16);
          tidedata1.innerHTML = `${TimeStart} - ${HightStart}m`;
          tidedata1Full.innerHTML = `${TimeStart}am - ${HightStart}m`;
        }
        if (TimeEnd.slice(11, 16) == end) {
          Date = TimeEnd.slice(0, 10);
          TimeEnd = TimeEnd.slice(11, 16);
          tidedata2.innerHTML = `${TimeEnd} - ${HightEnd}m`;
          tidedata2Full.innerHTML = `${TimeEnd}pm - ${HightEnd}m`;
        }
      }
    

      if (i < day) {
        square.classList.add("disabled");
      }
      square2.append(tidedata1Full, tidedata2Full);
      square.append(monthNum, tidedata1, tidedata2, square2);
      inner_grid.append(square);
    }
  });

calendar.append(month, inner_grid);
```

At the moment it will get the correct data but only for one day and then it just repeats that same data over all of the days.

the data structure look like

Answer (score 0):

Using a for-each loop to go over every point of data in the array.
And then append the data to where it needs to go. In this case to the calendar and its divs.

```
lowHigh.forEach(d =>{
    let wDate = new Date(d.time).getUTCDate();
    let wHour = 6;
    let eHour = 18;
    wHour = ("0" + wHour).slice(-2);
    let wMintue = new Date(d.time).getUTCMinutes();
    wMintue = ("0" + wHour).slice(-2);
    if(wDate == i+1)
        {
            if(tidedata1.innerHTML == "")
            {
                
                tidedata1.innerHTML = `${wHour}:${wMintue} - ${d.value}m`
                tidedata1Full.innerHTML = `${wHour}:${wMintue}am - ${d.value}m`
            }
            else
            {
                tidedata2.innerHTML = `${eHour}:${wMintue} - ${d.value}m`
                tidedata2Full.innerHTML = `${eHour}:${wMintue}pm - ${d.value}m`
            }
        }
    })

    if(i < day)
    {
        square.classList.add("disabled");
    }
    square2.append(tidedata1Full, tidedata2Full)
    square.append(monthNum,tidedata1,tidedata2, square2);
    inner_grid.append(square);
    }

})
```